# QRegExp no working with strings starting with character '='

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I'm using QRegExp in the following way:

```
QStringList variables;
QRegExp re("([A-Z]+\\d+)");
QString formula = "=+(AB2)-A11*1.1";
int pos = 0;
while ((pos = re.indexIn(formula, pos)) != -1) {
  variables << re.cap(1);
  pos += re.matchedLength();
}
qDebug()<<variables;
```

It should print the following: `("AB2", "A11")`, however it prints `()`; an empty list. But if I remove the character `=` at the beginning of string `formula`, it works and works with any other character at beginning except for character `=`.

Any Ideas of why it is?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I get your expected output when I run this. What version of Qt are you using? Are you sure you've shown us the code that doesn't seem to be working for you?

Comment: I'm using Version: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5

Comment: And you're sure this is the code that doesn't work? If you copy and paste *exactly* what you've posted here, compile and run it, you are sure that the output gives you an empty list?

Comment: I'm sorry, that code works correctly and actually every thing works Ok. I wasn't doing things right. Ignore my question and thank you so much for answering.